# Why does pushing a new branch pointer to the Git remote result in a pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I pushed a reference to a branch to the remote, that I'd renamed locally, like this, using a git bash command line:

`git push origin new-branch-name:refs/heads/new-branch-name`

I got the following output:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: Create pull request for new-branch-name:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/my-organisation/my-repo-name/pull-requests/new?source=new-branch-name&t=1
remote:
To https://bitbucket.org/my-organisation/my-app-name.git
 * [new branch]      new-branch-name -> new-branch-name
```

My understanding of a pull request is that it's a request for one branch to be merged into another. So why does a pull request get created just because I pushed a pointer? And why is no pull request visible to me in BitBucket? I don't see a 'merge' happening (which is what I usually do in BitBucket to complete or 'close' the pull request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is actually creating a pull request.  Instead, this is a link you can follow if you *want* to create a new pull request.

It's very common for folks to push a branch just to open a pull request with that branch, so they provide the link if you want it, so you don't need to search through the interface to do so.  If you don't want to do so, then just ignore it, and no pull request will be created.